# Is there a standard for whether a class under test should be constructed in a fixture or in a test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, fixtures

I'm just curious, are there any standard guidelines that state whether an instance of a class under test should be constructed in a fixture or in the actual test case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a standard reference on that topic. Here's what I'd do:

If I had only one test to write, or if I needed an instance of the class under test that was constructed differently than any other instance of that class in my test suite, I'd just instantiate it in the test. Why make it any more complicated that you have to? If I needed to use the same instance over and over again, I'd put it in a fixture.

I do think it's important to construct only the fixtures you need for a given test case, so that there's nothing to mislead the reader. That means either using whatever scoping mechanism your test framework provides (e.g. an rspec `context` block or a whole new xUnit TestCase) to construct a given fixture only before the tests that need it, or moving instance construction from fixtures to test. To avoid duplication, you can always write a method to construct an instance and call it from as many tests as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid putting anything inside a fixture.
After a while the CUT state tends to get out of hand as the number of tests in that fixture increase. Each test require a simialr but different behavior which could or could not be added to some initialization/setup method.
Having the CUT in the fixture level creates a shared states between the tests which can cause test failure due to run order - which is a pain to find and fix.

Another readability issue happens when a test fails - people tend to forget the initialization that might have happened in another method.

There are better ways to avoid code duplication - Using AutoMocking container to create objects with fake parameters or Factory methods which enable a different initialization for each test (if required) and create more readable and maintainable tests.